# custom tab to product detail page fro configurable products only

Tags: magento

i used below code to add custom tab to product detail page

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
   <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
   <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
```

now i want to show it only for configurable product what should i do for it ?..

Answer (score 0):

You should add your code in "PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable" handle in catalog.xml instead of "catalog_product_view" .
Start fro 275 line change :

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
<label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description"
           template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
        <action method="addToParentGroup">
            <group>detailed_info</group>
        </action>
        <action method="setTitle" translate="value">
            <value>Description</value>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data"
           template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.configurable.extra" as="product_type_data_extra"
               translate="label">
            <label>Product Extra Info</label>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
<reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable"
           as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: can u write excat line